# Passar parametro GET pelo AJAX para ativar pagina

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Estou precisando fazer o redirecionamento apos fazer alguns comandos no php preciso carregar um ajax.

O link que envia para pagina PHP:

```
href="ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?a=1&c=MEMBR&pb=3&p=vinculo.php?c=MEMBR"
```

Após isto recebo no php do deletaPessoaVinculo.php

```
$w_COD_IDENT_VINCU = ( isset($_GET['c']) ? $_GET['c'] : "" );
$w_COD_IDENT_PESSO = ( isset($_GET['pb']) ? $_GET['pb'] : "" );
$w_acao = ( isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : "" );
$w_pagina = ( isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : '');
```

Faço o que preciso fazer na página e no final faço:

```
header('Location: ajax/'. $w_pagina);
```

Porém não está retornando.

Na verdade quero deletar algo, e ao remover quero da um `reload` na página.

Comment: No console do browser, quando você faz essa requisição, ela esta sendo redirecionada? creio eu, que ela faz o `redirect` na requisição ajax que você fez, aconselho a você usar algum retorno em vez do `redirect` e dependendo desse retorno você faz o reload através do `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo, provavelmente porque o último parâmetro `p` está com a url `p=vinculo.php?c=MEMBR`, e há um `?`, que significa que irá começar a parte de `queryString`, porém esta parte já começou, teste deixar o parâmetro da url, ficando:

```
href="ajax/deletaPessoaVinculo.php?a=1&c=MEMBR&pb=3&p=vinculo"
```

e ao dar o redirecionar fazer isso:

```
header('Location: ajax/'. $w_pagina . ".php?c=" . $w_COD_IDENT_VINCU);
```

Abs.

Comment: A sua indicação resolveu o problema, apesar de não ter utilizado este método para o mesmo, eu fiz dando include na página, pois o request ainda estava acessível.